# A callback was provided to intercept the upstream response, but a network error occurred while making the request

Tags: cypress

I am using the method described in the answer of this question [Log network failures in Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73195345/log-network-failures-in-cypress/73200916#73200916) to log network failures. I basically intercept every failing request and its response and log it in some array as follows:

```js
cy.intercept('*', (request) => {
    request.continue(response => {
      if(response.statusMessage !== "OK") {
        networkFails.push({request, response})
      }
    })
  })
```

The tests run perfectly fine, the problem is at the end of the tests I get this error
[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like a web socket error, but I don't think your intercept is handling those. You can verify by commenting out `request.continue()` and seeing if it goes away.

Comment: Yes the error goes away, but without the continue function, I won't be able to log responses. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: You would need to look into why this request is erroring, there may be clues on devtools network tab - please post any red lines listed there. It's expected behavior from Cypress, if a request fails and it has an intercept, Cypress sends that message. Note, the request is failing not the response so your code is still valid.

Comment: Is there a way I can bypass that error? Because I log these network failures to a file for later debugging anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, and it turns out using `request.continue` is what was causing it.

`request.continue` is expecting a response, but when you get a `socket hangup` (`ConnResetException`), or in my case the socket being closed before it was finished writing, it triggers a cypress error.

**Instead of `request.continue`, you'll want to use `request.on( 'response', response => {`**

Your full code snippet should look like this:

```
cy.intercept('*', (request) => {
    request.on( 'response', response => {
      if(response.statusMessage !== "OK") {
        networkFails.push({request, response})
      }
    })
  })
```

The cypress documentation does a great job of explaining all of the different options here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Request-events

For reference, this was the specific cypress error I was getting while using `.continue()`. The error message was a bit different from yours but essentially the same problem requiring the same solution.

```
A callback was provided to intercept the upstream response, but a network error occurred while making the request:

Error: Socket closed before finished writing response
```

Comment: How do you catch the error and continue? There is no response to that one, the request failed.